# How to print single value of entity without dumping the whole object?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get one single value from entity.Can anyone help me here.
Here is my code.Please let me know what is missing here.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM AdminBundle:MailTemplates e  WHERE e.keyword = '" .$keywordVal."'");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->getResult();
echo $result ->getId();
```

Here i want the 'id'.

Comment: `SELECT e.columnName FROM` ...

Comment: On a sidenote: don't paste queries, look at tom's answer on how to use parameters with invariant query text or, better yet, avoid SQL/DQL and use the standard `findBy*()` methods for this simple case. You shouldn't be concerned about getting whole entities back from DB, performance is not impacted much as long as you don't have various KB of data. Instead, focus on security, which is clearly lacking in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is noted in the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) how you can do this.

So given you're code this will become:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e.id FROM AdminBundle:MailTemplates e WHERE e.keyword = ?1");
$query->setParameter(1, $keywordVal);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->getResult(); // array of MailTemplates ids
```

Note: I also made use of [setParameters](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#named-and-positional-parameters) instead of setting the value directly in the query.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
$this->get('database_connection')->fetchColumn('select id from mail_templates where...');
```

That's much better for performance and much easier if you don't want to have a deal with query builder and other doctrine orm stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Using the query builder you could do...

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder('e');

$queryBuilder
    ->select('e.yourColumn')
    // This will return just this column
    // Alternatively you could omit any select to return the whole object
    // that you could then use like $object->getYourColumn() if you so chose

    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('e.keyword', ':keyword'))
    ->setParameter('keyword', $keyword)
;

return $queryBuilder
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this on loading Entities instead of creating own queries
Loading the entity with the Repository.

```
$rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("Bundlename:Entity");

//find one by keyword -> single entity
$entity = $rep->findOneBy(array('keyword' => $keyword));

//find all by keyword - Array of entities 
$result = $rep->findBy(array('keyword' => $keyword));
```

Comment: I think your answer is missing the point. The OP wants to retrieve only one field (i.e. column) of the enties. The question is *not* how to search/filter entities.